# Swift sort core data by date (not just time)

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3, nssortdescriptor

I'm building a app in Swift using core data. I'm using task Entities with due attribute that is a Date. I need to sort the tasks according to this due date.

I tried using a NSSortDescriptor with key due

```
NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "due", ascending: false)
```

**Issue:**

It sorts my data by time only - not considering the day/month/year

here is the data I got from my fetch request:

```
Optional(2017-02-06 03:29:18 +0000)
Optional(2017-02-08 03:29:27 +0000)
Optional(2017-02-07 03:29:38 +0000)
Optional(2017-02-08 03:30:29 +0000)
```

**How can I sort it by what comes sooner? (considering the whole NSDate not just the time portion)**

I want it to be:

```
Optional(2017-02-06 03:29:18 +0000)
Optional(2017-02-07 03:29:38 +0000)
Optional(2017-02-08 03:29:27 +0000)
Optional(2017-02-08 03:30:29 +0000)
```

**Complete Code**
    All tasks completed are 0 in the list and I'm calling:

```
helper(showComp: true, sortBy: NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "due", ascending: false))
```

helper func:

```
func helper(showComp: Bool, sortBy: NSSortDescriptor?){
let g = cur as! Group
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
    return
}

let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Task")
let sortDescriptor0 =  NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "completed", ascending: true)
let sortDescriptor =  NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "index", ascending: true)
if sortBy == nil {
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor0, sortDescriptor]
}else{
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor0, sortBy!]
}
if (cur as! Group).name != "All"{
    var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "group = %@", argumentArray: [g])
    if !showComp {
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "group = %@ && completed = %@", argumentArray: [g, 0])
    }
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
}
do {
    groups = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

**Photo of the core data attribute**
[image]

Comment: Can you show the actual code? Because I'm not sure how it's possible for the predicate to work as you're describing. Also, that `NSSortDescriptor` that you create specifies `ascending: false`, but the dates as you want them ARE in ascending order.

Comment: It is looks like that your due field is type of `String` in the `CoreData` not `Date` type.

Comment: Updated my question. I included the code @DaveWeston.

Comment: The due is of type Date (included screenshot now) @NiravD. I'm printing it out just to see what I get.

Comment: It's returns only date object. Use "due" as String attribute. Now you can create a new date object use date formatter and convert to string. That's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift 3

```
var sdSortDate = NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "date", ascending: false)
fr.sortDescriptors = [sdSortDate]
let result4 = try! context.fetch(fr)
```

I tested it in Swift 3, works well

```
[<NSManagedObject: 0x618000089060> (entity: CoreDate; id: 0x61800002c460 <x-coredata://E7D9FD6F-5DCF-464B-93BF-D1609BF35695/CoreDate/p3> ; data: {
    date = "2017-02-09 21:35:19 +0000";
}), <NSManagedObject: 0x61800008b680> (entity: CoreDate; id: 0x60000002c140 <x-coredata://E7D9FD6F-5DCF-464B-93BF-D1609BF35695/CoreDate/p1> ; data: {
    date = "2017-02-06 04:41:59 +0000";
}), <NSManagedObject: 0x60800008c080> (entity: CoreDate; id: 0x60800002d460 <x-coredata://E7D9FD6F-5DCF-464B-93BF-D1609BF35695/CoreDate/p2> ; data: {
    date = "2017-02-17 18:28:39 +0000";
})]

After sort

[<NSManagedObject: 0x61800008b680> (entity: CoreDate; id: 0x60000002c140 <x-coredata://E7D9FD6F-5DCF-464B-93BF-D1609BF35695/CoreDate/p1> ; data: {
    date = "2017-02-06 04:41:59 +0000";
}), <NSManagedObject: 0x618000089060> (entity: CoreDate; id: 0x61800002c460 <x-coredata://E7D9FD6F-5DCF-464B-93BF-D1609BF35695/CoreDate/p3> ; data: {
    date = "2017-02-09 21:35:19 +0000";
}), <NSManagedObject: 0x60800008c080> (entity: CoreDate; id: 0x60800002d460 <x-coredata://E7D9FD6F-5DCF-464B-93BF-D1609BF35695/CoreDate/p2> ; data: {
    date = "2017-02-17 18:28:39 +0000";
})]
```

Comment: is the date attribute of type Date? or String?

Comment: The type of date attribute  is Date